# Numeric Integral as a function

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I have..

```
w = 10^9*NIntegrate[Cos[u*x]/(1 + 10^-7*I*Sqrt[u^2 - 0.006^2])*(u*Sin[u/2])/(
u^2 - 0), {u, 0, 10^8, \[Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 10^8]
```

I want to plot w as a function of x..but the integration can not be determined without the values of x, as attempt:

```
tab1 = Table[{x, w}, {x, 1/10, 1, 1/10}];Table[{ListLinePlot[ta = Table[{x /. tab1[[i, 1]], Re[w /. tab1[[i, 2, j]]]}, {i, 1, 
  20}], Epilog -> Point[ta], PlotLabel -> Re, AxesLabel -> {x, w}], ListLinePlot[ta = Table[{x /. tab1[[i, 1]], Im[w /. tab1[[i, 2, j]]]}, {i, 1, 
  20}], Epilog -> Point[ta], PlotLabel -> Im,AxesLabel -> {x, w}]}, {j, 1, 1}]
```

But I did not get the wanted graph.

Comment: a bit aside but this is not an intergral equation, its just an integral.

Comment: It is  function involves integral..

Comment: "Integral equation" has a specific meaning. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_equation . This is not one. I have fixed the title.

Comment: Thank you george2079!

Answer (score 2):

If we define w as a function with NumericQ as a pattern filter, we can get a much simpler expression for the plots:

```
w[x_?NumericQ] := 10^9*NIntegrate[Cos[u*x]/(1 + 10^-7*I*Sqrt[u^2 - 0.006^2])
    *(u*Sin[u/2])/(u^2 - 0), {u, 0, Infinity}]
```

If you're willing to sit around for a while as the plots generate, then directly plotting the real and imaginary components works fine:

```
Plot[Re[w[x]],{x,0,10}]

Plot[Im[w[x]],{x,0,10}]
```

However, w[x] is difficult to compute and fairly poorly behaved as written, so this will take quite a bit of time. If you'd rather have the most basic outline of the nature of the graph, then making a table of values is probably easier:

```
tab1 = Table[{x,Re[#],Im[#]}&[w[x]], {x,1/10,10,1/10}];
```

To avoid having to compute w[x] multiple times, I used an anonymous function `{x,Re[#],Im[#]}&` to extract the real and imaginary components from the same computation of w[x].

Then to plot the real part, you need to plot the first and second member of every element:

```
ListLinePlot[tab1[[1;;-1,{1,2}]]]
```

And the imaginary part is plotted by plotting the first and third member of every element:

```
ListLinePlot[tab1[[1;;-1,{1,3}]]]
```

Comment: NumericQ filter solves my problem easily!! Many Thanks!!!